# How to prevent user to edit system proxy in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, proxy, administrator

I want my users to use local proxy, but I set it with admin user and even I login as a user, he or she can edit or add new proxy or even turn it off. How can I restrict that, so may only admin will use that stuff.